# Effective way in PRESTO to Result output with Boolean values

Tags: sql, database, presto

Im trying to create a output of boolen values on back of some conditions.

**OutPut:**
[image]

**EX:** I have 3 rules/conditions from different tables which are not related to each other.

**Rule 1:**

```sql
Select USER_NAME, ID from session_user where age > 25
```

**Rule 2:**

```sql
Select USER_NAME, ID from current_user where plan = 'gold'
```

**Rule 3:**

```sql
Select USER_NAME, ID from customer where group_name='managers'
```

My OutPut Should be:

```
USER_NAME   |  ID | Rule 1 | Rule 2 | Rule 3

user1          1     true    false    true

user2          2     false   true     true

user3          3     true    true     true
```

If `user1` is passing rule one the value should be `true` for him in the output, if he passed `rule 2` then `true` else `false`.

**Solution:**

```sql
SELECT  dp.USER_NAME,
        dp.ID, 
        CASE 
            WHEN dp.sex='F' THEN 'True' 
            ELSE 'False' 
        END AS Rule_1,
        CASE 
            WHEN dp.sex='M' THEN 'True' 
            ELSE 'False' 
        END AS Rule_2,
        CASE 
            WHEN dp.sex not in ('M','F') THEN 'True' 
            ELSE 'False' 
        END AS Rule_3
FROM    user_details dp where dp.Organisation='007';
```

**Question:**

1. Is the above select statement is effective way in PRESTO.?
2. If not what are the other options.
3. Im new to PRESTO so its difficult to use join in select, How do i form similar output when i join multiple tables? any doc links will be helpful to understand further.
4. With `CASE` I cant able to use `COUNT` how can i add a rule if i want to see `COUNT` is greater than 2. (Count(*) > 0) = True else False.
5. Can we use `SubQuery` in `CASE`? Will it affect performance?

Comment: Your current approach is perfectly acceptable in general.

Comment: But im facing some issues when i do `COUNT` and is there any doc around how we can do conditions on join operations? @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrestoDB supports boolean values, so no `CASE` expression is necessary:

```
SELECT dp.USER_NAME, dp.ID, 
       (dp.sex = 'F') AS Rule_1,
       (dp.sex = 'M') AS Rule_2,
       (dp.sex not in ('M','F')) AS Rule_3
FROM user_details dp 
WHERE dp.Organisation = '007';
```

PrestoDB (like all databases) supports subqueries in `CASE` expressions.

Comment: Would be advice me on how we can use `COUNT` and query on Join operations too use in rules pls?

Comment: @DonOfDen . . . Ask a *new* question where such a `COUNT()` and `JOIN` would be appropriate.

Comment: raised a new question with details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62874110/effective-way-to-use-count-and-join-in-presto-case-statements.