# Effective way To use Count and JOIN in PRESTO CASE statements

Tags: sql, presto

This is on back of a question raised earlier on [`Effective way in PRESTO to Result output with boolen values`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873767/effective-way-in-presto-to-result-output-with-boolean-values). Please refer the question for more details.

On back of the question two solutions are availabe.

```sql
SELECT  dp.USER_NAME,
        dp.ID, 
        CASE 
            WHEN dp.sex='F' THEN 'True' 
            ELSE 'False' 
        END AS Rule_1,
        CASE 
            WHEN dp.sex='M' THEN 'True' 
            ELSE 'False' 
        END AS Rule_2,
        CASE 
            WHEN dp.sex not in ('M','F') THEN 'True' 
            ELSE 'False' 
        END AS Rule_3
FROM    user_details dp where dp.Organisation='007';
```

```sql
SELECT dp.USER_NAME, dp.ID, 
       (dp.sex = 'F') AS Rule_1,
       (dp.sex = 'M') AS Rule_2,
       (dp.sex not in ('M','F')) AS Rule_3
FROM user_details dp 
WHERE dp.Organisation = '007';
```

**Questions:**

With CASE I cant able to use `COUNT` how can i add a rule if i want to see COUNT is greater than 2. (Count(*) > 0) = True else False with JOIN Tables to the selected Query?

Is there a way to user `COUNT` in case?

What im trying to create:

```sql
SELECT dp.USER_NAME, dp. ID, 
       (dp.sex = 'F') AS Rule_1,
       (dp.sex = 'M') AS Rule_2,
       (dp.sex not in ('M','F')) AS Rule_3,
       (dp.DateOfBirth NOT BETWEEN timestamp '1986-04-01' AND timestamp '2001-03-31') AS Rule_4,
       (count(up.*)>10) AS Rule_5,
FROM user_details dp 
JOIN user_purchase up on up.user_id=dp.id
where dp.Organisation='007';
```

In the above query i'm trying to post a Boolean value if the `user_purchase` table last data > 10, that particular row output value should be `True` else `False`.

```
USER_NAME   |  ID | Rule 1 | Rule 2 | Rule 3 | Rule 4 | Rule 5

user1          1     true    false    true     true     true

user2          2     false   true     true     true     true

user3          3     true    true     true     true     false
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  Add sample input and output data and don't leave any part of your question to speculation.

Comment: I have updated my question with sample details @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: You can't mix `COUNT` this way with the other boolean expressions.  You will either need to drop the new select term, or add `GROUP BY` to your query and convert the boolean expressions to aggregates.